# Using Expect with an ant build file

Tags: bash, ant, sh, expect

I have a command line program and I'm trying to automate interaction with that program using Expect.  The program is launch by the running the command "ant runconsole" on the build file.

I also embedded the Expect script in a bash script. Currently my code looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $HOME/myProj/build

/usr/bin/expect - << EndMark

spawn ant runconsole

EndMark

exit 0
```

Build this just prints spawn ant runconsole to terminal. And putting "ant runconsole" in quotes returns "couldn't execute "ant runconsole": no such file or directory while executing "spawn "ant runconsole""

This is my first time using Expect so I'm sure this is a really noobish question, but I couldn't find the solution online. I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening there is that you are creating an Expect session with Ant, but not interacting with it, so it terminates.

You could modify your script slightly thus:

```
/usr/bin/expect - << EndMark
spawn ant -v runconsole
expect
EndMark
```

Run that, and you should see some output from Ant returned.  For information on how to set up your Expect script, and the interaction with Ant, perhaps see the [spawn wiki page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10045) or [Expect man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html).

Comment: Thank you! For anyone else who reads this, I also had to put an 'expect eof' before the end mark before it would begin accepting my send requests.